# Asp.Net Webform custom view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, webforms

I search a way to do a custom view engine on ASP.NET Webform as MVC.
The goal is to be able to check if a view exist before this one is loaded, and if this view exist load this one otherwise load a default view.

Do you know if there is a way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to write code for custom view engine just for this situation. You can handle this case using below code snippet.

```
 protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
 {
    if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(InvalidOperationException))
    {
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    base.OnException(filterContext);
 }
```

I presume you must have base controller for your application. Just paste above code in that.

Hope it helps you.